# personalize session list on (KDM|GDM|LightDM|some_other)

Tags: lightdm, gdm, kdm

A bit of an odd question:

I want to change the list of sessions available on (KDM|GDM|LightDM|some_other) to a user, without affecting the sessions available to others.

Specifically, I have one user that is not very computer-savvy, and I want to prevent the said user from changing session type accidentally. I dont want this to affect the other users.

Can it be done ? I'd gladly switch my display manager to whatever one supports this

Comment: The list of default system sessions come from the desktop files in `/usr/share/xsessions`. But I don't know if it's possible to change the list of sessions for one particular user.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, it's not possible without modifying Unity Greeter (and maybe also lightdm).  All the valid sessions listed in /usr/share/xsessions will be shown.